# Mostrar imagens cadastradas no banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Sou iniciante, não sei como mostrar imagens salvas pelo nome no banco de dados

```
 // function 
 function cadastraUsuario($conn, $nome_topper, $email_topper, $senha_topper, 
 $data_nasc_topper, $sexo_topper) { 
 $query = "INSERT INTO participantes (nome_topper, email_topper, 
 senha_topper, data_nasc_topper, sexo_topper) " . "VALUES ('{$nome_topper}', 
 '{$email_topper}', '{$senha_topper}', '{$data_nasc_topper}', 
 '{$sexo_topper}')"; return mysqli_query($conn, $query); } – 


// CODIGO DE CADASTRO, FUNCIONANDO
$nome_topper = "$_POST[nome] $_POST[sobrenome]";
$email_topper = $_POST['email'];
$senha_topper_1 = $_POST['senha1'];
$senha_topper_2 = $_POST['senha2'];
$data_nasc_topper = $_POST['dataNasc'];
$sexo_topper = $_POST['sexo'];
if (isset($_FILES['imagem'])) {
$extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'], -4));
$novo_nome = md5(time()) . $extensao;
$diretorio = "upload/";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

$query2 = "insert into participantes (arquivo, data_upload) values ('$novo_nome', now())";
mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

if ($senha_topper_1 == $senha_topper_2) {
    if (idade($data_nasc_topper) >= 18) {
        if (cadastraUsuario($conn, $nome_topper, $email_topper, $senha_topper_1, $data_nasc_topper, $sexo_topper)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
            $_SESSION['nome_logado'] = $nome_topper;
            $_SESSION['foto_logado'] = "";
            $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
            header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            $msg = mysqli_error($conn);
            $_SESSION["danger"] = "Usuário não cadastrado: $msg";
            $msg = mysqli_error($conn);
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "Usuário menor de 18 anos.";
        header("location: formCadastrar.php");
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION["danger"] = "As senhas são diferentes.";
    header("location: formCadastrar.php");
} else {
$_SESSION["danger"] = "A imagem esta errada tente novamente";
    header("location: formCadastrar.php");
}
```

Comment: Existe uma falha no seu sistema de cadastro e você terá que solucioná-la antes de prosseguir com a exibição das imagens. Quando o usuário se cadastra no seu sistema, ele faz o upload da imagem, porém você não está gravando o `ID` do usuário na tabela `participantes`. Sem isso, você não irá conseguir dizer qual imagem pertence a um determinado usuário no momento de exibi-la.

Comment: como posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Pelo que percebi, você insere o usuário através da função: `cadastraUsuario()`, certo? O problema é que você faz a inserção da imagem antes de inserir o usuário, então ele ainda não terá um `ID` na sua tabela de usuários. Você teria que inserir o usuário antes, pegar o [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php) e então gerar o `INSERT` da imagem passando esse `ID`. Pode me corrigir se eu estiver errado, estou dizendo isso com base no trecho do seu código que foi postado.

Comment: Adicione essa função editando sua publicação, por favor.